# Header Text Color Change on Hover

Tags: css, text, colors, header, hover

The header section is transparent at the top of the page but when you hover on the section it turns to white. But I can't find a way to turn the header text black when I hover over the header section.

I can easily set the menu link/item to change to black, but I can’t see how to change the whole header text

but then again everything inside has to turn black. not just the header text. the logo, the social icons etc.. i am really having trouble figuring this out.

Please, can someone provide some assistance?

this is the example i want to achieve: https://firstsight.design/cherie/hair/

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to whatever you want to change when you hover over, then in CSS, write:  `your-class:hover { // the style}`

Using `:hover` after the id/class name will make it so when you hover over an element, it will change to that style

*NOTE: Use a class for multiple items, use an id for a single item

Answer (score 0):

It seems like they are simply using `filter: invert(1);` on the header.

Here I made this example for you which works exactly like your linked website.

```css
body{
  background-image: url("https://news.cgtn.com/news/77416a4e3145544d326b544d354d444d3355444f31457a6333566d54/img/37d598e5a04344da81c76621ba273915/37d598e5a04344da81c76621ba273915-1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color:transparent;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

img{
  max-height: 100px;
}

.whiteblack{
  color: white;
}


.header:hover {
  background-color: black;
   filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<img class="whiteblack" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.iconsdb.com%2Ficons%2Fpreview%2Fwhite%2Fspeech-bubble-4-xxl.png&f=1&nofb=1">
  <div class="whiteblack">link 1</div>
  <div class="whiteblack">link 2</div>
  <div class="whiteblack">link 3</div>
  <div class="whiteblack">link 4</div>
  <div class="whiteblack">link 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can change what you want in **element`:hover`**

e.g. Changing the text and background color  of header section:

```css
body {
   background-color:#cdf;
}

#header {
   padding: 20px 10px;
   text-align: center;
   color: #000;
   transition: color 0.7s, background-color 0.7s
}

#header:hover {
   background-color: #000;
   color: #fff
}
```

```html
<body>

   <div id="header">
      This is a header! Bring your mouse/finger over me.
   </div>

</body>
```

- Read more on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover
- Keep reading about CSS Selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

«Hope it was helpful»